# Unusual growth tempdb

Tags: sql-server, database, dynamics-ax-2012, tempdb

My question is the following:
Scope:
I am currently using Microsoft Dynamics Ax 2012 R3 and my database has the following settings in the properties of the tempdb in Microsoft Sql Server 2012.

[image: TempDbConfig]

Actualmente tengo un disco de  29 GB para almacenar la base de dato  tempdb.

[image: DiskSizeOfMyTempdb]

But the last few days I have seen that my tempdb database has a runaway growth and it takes 2 days to fill the 29 GB disk.

Questions:

1. Are there any settings in Microsoft Dynamics Ax 2012 R3 that allow this behavior?
2. If there is a behavior that impacts me in the tempdb, how could I solve it?
3. Is there a problem in my tempdb configuration?
4. What configuration do you recommend for the tempdb?

Comment: AX2012 will use the tempdb database to store AX buffers for `tempDB` type tables. The tables are left there for future reuse and are only dropped when the last AOS service of your environment is stopped. Periodically restarting the AOS'es will remove unused `tempDB` tables from the tempdb database. Heavy batch activity can stress the tempdb database. Count the tables from the tempdb database and look for those named `t123_AEF335FD4...` (`t`=table + `123`=AX table id + `_` + `AEF335FD4...`=unique hexadecimal string). Looking up the AX table id could point to a specific process.

Comment: Theres a list of all tables in the tempdb https://gist.github.com/pablo17sanchez/733b2e870b3d3130a16a8ab5b9291e70

Comment: Can you help me detect the problem??

Comment: The AX temp tables with IDs `100003` and `100145` appear to be the most frequent. Look them up on your environment and see if you can explain their frequent occurance. Also, is the Recovery Model of the tempdb database set to "simple" and what happens if you limit the tempdb database further (reduce maxsize for the `tempdev` and `templog` files to 2048 MB)?